# What is the product of an empty family of similiar algebras, that is $\prod\langle \mathbf{A}_i \ | \ i \in I \rangle $, where $I = \emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What is the product of an empty family of similiar algebras, that is  $\prod\langle \mathbf{A}_i \mid i \in I \rangle $, where $I = \emptyset$?

The family $\langle \mathbf{A}_i \mid i \in \emptyset \rangle $ equals $\emptyset$ beacuse the function $i \colon \emptyset \mapsto X$ (whatever the $X$ is) is the empty function $\emptyset$.

So the question is: what is $\prod \emptyset$? Is it $\{ \emptyset \}$?

Am I right? I believe it is, but I haven't a step-by-step explanation. What is the universum of such product? How does a function interpretation look like (and more important: why?)

Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I've never seen the notation $\prod x$ without indices. Can you provide the definition of  $\prod x$, for an arbitrary $x$?

Comment: Or the definition of $\prod\langle \mathbf{A}_i \ | \ i \in I \rangle$.

Comment: Yes. As a set, the product is the collection of all functions $f$ with domain $I$ such that for all $i\in I$ we have $f(i)\in|\mathbf A_i|$, where $|\mathbf M|$ is the universe of the algebra $\mathbf M$. If $I=\emptyset$, the only such function is the empty function.

Comment: @Git Gut. $\prod \langle \mathbf{A}_i \ | \ i \in I \rangle$ denotes the same object as $\prod_{i \in I} \mathbf{A}_i$.

Comment: Then it's as Andres said. See the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_products) entry on this. Which isn't surprising considering that the empty sum yields its neutral element, so does the empty product (since $\{\varnothing \}$=1).

Answer (score 1):

To cut down on the number of unanswered questions, here we go.

Given any set of sets $\{B_i\}_{i\in I},$ we have by definition that $$\prod_{i\in I}B_i:=\left\{f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\mid\forall i\in I,f(i)\in B_i\right\},$$ so when $I=\emptyset,$ this is clearly just the set containing the empty function $\emptyset,$ and nothing else.